String value changing from the one inputed
Im writing a code that asks the user to input a string and then a character, and it will count how many of those characters are in the string. For some reason, my character is different than the one inputed.
value = input("Input a string: ")
char = str(input("Input a character to count: "))
count = 0
for char in value:
    count += 1
print(f"The character '{char}' appears {count} times.")


Your loop has bound char to a different value than originally input. That name is not "local" to the loop. We can see this with a simple test.
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> for a in a: pass
...
>>> a
3

Simple solution: change the name.
You also aren't testing that each character is one you're looking for.
You also don't need to convert the result of input to a string. It already is.
value = input("Input a string: ")
char = input("Input a character to count: ")
count = 0
for ch in value:
    if ch == char:
        count += 1
print(f"The character '{char}' appears {count} times.")


The reasons for your code not working having been explained in other answers, know that strings implement the count method, so you could simply do:
print(f"The character '{char}' appears {value.count(char)} times.")

You are overwriting the value of char which each loop iteration. This code will behave as you expect:
value = input("Input a string: ")
char = input("Input a character to count: ")[0]
count = 0
for c in value:
    if c == char:
        count += 1
print(f"The character '{char}' appears {count} times.")


Looks like what you meant was this:
value = iter(input("Input a string: "))
char = str(input("Input a character to count: "))
count = 0
while char in value:
    count += 1
print(f"The character '{char}' appears {count} times.")

This doesn't re-assign char and instead just looks for its occurrences. (I just changed for to while and made value an iterator.)
Attempt This Online!

@simon char in value iterates over value, returning True when it finds char, or False when it reaches the end. And the while simply uses those True/False values. Best reference I know is Membership test operations, which talks about in and the iteration search (although for "user-defined classes").
